# Can we calculate a vector field from the pressure field with Navier Stokes?

Tags: computational-mathematics, fluid-dynamics, simulation, stokes-theorem

I've been looking for weeks and can't seem to wrap my head around CFD or the computation of fluid and its movement in 2D with Navier Stokes.

Without an initial velocity field, and given ONLY a pressure field, can you reverse engineer and find the velocity field from this, or is this impossible, or the literal point of Navier Stokes?
I might be in the complete wrong for what I should be trying to find out because I simply don't know what I don't know. I just want to further my understanding and be able to make a small simulator for fluids with added pressure and see it's movement with time.

Navier-Stokes uses pressure and velocity fields to calculate the change in velocity over time. This is just something that I  don't have in this case. Is it possible?

It's hard to get an answer on this because not many people from what I've seen have no initial velocity, and I'm not sure what I should be learning...

Any help would be extremely appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean knowing the pressure field everywhere at a given time or knowing the entire pressure field for all times (in an interval $[0,T]$ for instance)? Also, are we talking compressible? incompressible? bounded domain? entire space?

Comment: @themaker I was thinking that the pressure field after the initial conditions could be calculated from the velocity, so given an original pressure field it could calculate a velocity field and go from there. I'm using the incompressible equations. My new question is more on the side of how to deal with the bounded domain: How do I make sure that the boundary 'keeps' everything in? Do I make all the calculations (for derivatives etc) when on the boundaries by taking the one bordering cell? Lock them with 0 velocity, 0 pressure? Thank you so much!